# Mobile number field accepts invalid number too

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a validation code that I use to validate mobile number. If I enter a mobile number with alphabets or any invalid number, it accepts that too. Can someone suggest what is wrong in this?

Thanks

```
    var g=document.getElementById('mobile').value;
    if (g.length == 0 )
    {
        alert( "Please Enter Mobile Number." );
        formn.mobile.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(g.length>0)
    {
      if((g.length<10)||(g.length>10))
      {
        alert( "Mobile number should be 10 digits");    
        document.getElementById('mobile').focus();
        return false;       
      }
      else
      {
        var h3=/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/;
        if(g.match(h3)!=null)
        {
        alert( "Please Enter Valid Mobile Number"); 
        document.getElementById('mobile').focus();
        return false;
        }
      }       
    }
```

**EDIT** : I was thinking of removing the condition of 10 digits and allow user to input the mobile numbers as per their choice and their own way and then replace/reformat using a regex so that only 10 digits mobile number goes into the database. During google search I found somewhere on stackoverflow that `^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$` works well for reformating in  following scenarios. Appreciate if someone can help me reformat it and show the reformatted digits when the user goes into the next textbox (losing focus)

```
9883443344
09883443344 
919883443344 
0919883443344    
+919883443344    
+91-9883443344 
0091-9883443344    
+91 -9883443344    
+91- 9883443344    
+91 - 9883443344 
0091 - 9883443344
```

Comment: `g.match(h3)!=null`: shouldn't this be `g.match(h3) === null` or `!h3.test(g)`?

Comment: General tip: it's easier to use `<input type="tel" maxlength="10" pattern=". . .">`.

Comment: well maxlength="10" is a good idea. Thanks for your advice but users type the numbers as per their choice so i edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

why not just use [0-9] as a regex, basicly if it is not in 0-9 it is invalid, maybe you want + for international calls that is 00 infront of phone number..

Please check out these testers also if you have not already:

http://www.regexpal.com/

https://regex101.com/

http://www.regexr.com/

```
var re = /[0-9+]/g; 
var str = '0700';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

If it is not in found with `/[0-9+]/g` it is not legal

Comment: Yes, you are right that gave me an idea to change the scenario a bit. I have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Use Below code :-

```
var g=document.getElementById('mobile').value;
    if (g.length == 0 )
    {
        alert( "Please Enter Mobile Number." );
        formn.mobile.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(g.length>0)
    {
      if((g.length<10)||(g.length>10))
      {
        alert( "Mobile number should be 10 digits");    
        document.getElementById('mobile').focus();
        return false;       
      }
      else
      {
        var h3=/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
        if(h3.test(document.getElementById('mobile').value) == false)
        {
        alert( "Please Enter Valid Mobile Number"); 
        document.getElementById('mobile').focus();
        return false;
        }
      }       
    }
```

Updated your regex code.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do away with the criteria of 10 digits after thinking a bit and have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression fits for all use-cases you mentioned and strictly rejects other patterns.

```
((00)|\+|0)?((91)|0)?\s{0,2}-?\s{0,2}(\d{10})
```

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling with how to replace the number entered by the user and make it a 10 digit number. I am trying to manipulate the code so that when the user inputs any number in any form and moves away from the input box, it should immediately change to a 10 digit number and display it in the input box. I have tried onclick, onblur but i am unable to trigger the event when the user moves the focus from the input box. Can you help? Thanks